# Opening a modal alert from a modal dialog

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

there!

In a .cshtml I have the following *div* element that acts a modal dialog to be showed when a certain radio option is selected:

```html
<div id="modalDesembolsos" class="modal modaldesembolso" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Informe dos valores anuais de desembolso</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="panel">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="text-center">Ano</th>
                                        <th class="text-right">Valor</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Anos, new SelectList(Model.Anos), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control text-right" })
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-right">
                                            <input type="number" id="valorAno" name="valorAno" class="dinheiro form-control" />
                                        </td>
                                        <th class="text-center"><input type="button" id="btnIncluiValorAnual" name="btnIncluiValorAnual" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="+" title="Inclui ano/valor" /></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <table id="tblRateio" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center">Ano</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <h4 class="acumulador text-right"></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnok" data-dissmiss="modal"> Ok </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btncancela" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Fechar"> Cancelar </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When user clicks the Ok button, the following jQuery function runs:

```js
        $('.btnok').click(function () {
            var acumulado = 0;
            $('#tblRateio > tbody > tr').each(function () {
                var anoGasto = $(this).find('.ano').text();
                var valor = parseFloat($(this).find(".valor").text().replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
                var desembolso = {
                    Ano: anoGasto,
                    Valor: valor
                };
                acumulado += valor;
                lstDesembolsos.push(desembolso);
            });
            if ($('#Valor').maskMoney('unmasked')[0] > acumulado) {
                lstDesembolsos = [];
                mostraMensagem("Inclusão de Item", "aviso", "A soma dos valores informados para desembolso é menor que o valor do item!");
                return false;
            }
            fecharModal();
        });
```

For each row of the table *tblRateio*, it sums the value of column that has the class *valor*. Then this accumulated is compared to another element value. If this comparison fails I want to show an alert message (but not that ugly one from js). I want it to act as a modal alert. That's why I wrote the function *mostraMensagem* that has the following code:

```js
function mostraMensagem(titulo, tipo, msg) {
    var classe = "";
    $('.modal-title').html(titulo);
    switch (tipo) {
        case "erro":
            classe = "alert-danger";
            break;
        case "sucesso":
            classe = "alert-success";
            break;
        case "info":
            classe = "alert-info";
            break;
        case "aviso":
            classe = "alert-warning";
            break;
    }
    $('.corpomensagem').addClass(classe);
    $('.corpomensagem').html(msg);
    $('#mensagens').show();
}
```

And the markup for that modal is the following:

```html
<div class="modal " id="mensagens" role="alert" tabindex="-2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close fecharmensagens" data-dissmiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Fechar">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="corpomensagem alert"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fecharmensagens" data-dissmiss="modal"> Ok </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, what is happening is that this modal alert message is loaded "behind" the modal dialog. Only when the modal dialog is closed the user can see the modal alert message. Certainly it's not the goal.

What shall I do to accomplish my goal?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards.
Paulo Ricardo Ferreira

Comment: Easiest way, you could close the modal before showing the alert.

Comment: @greenhoorn, this behavior is not the best one for the situation because the user shall insert more values in the modal dialog. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean something like [this](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html)? Look at the stackable one.

Comment: @greenhoorn, may be. Sort of. I try that.

Comment: @greenhoorn, I took a look at that and I noticed a slight difference. User clicks a button (that has this propertie: data-toggle="modal") with the specific purpose to open another modal. That's not my case. When the user clicks the Ok in my code the modal will be showed or not. Thanks.

Comment: That's true, but what prevents you to implement your own logic?

Comment: @greenhoorn, I believe it's my lack of knowledgment in both bootstrap and jQuery. :-( Thanks and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the z-index of the alert modal. Set it more than the modal that hides it.

**CSS**

```
#mensagens {
   z-index:1550; 
/*1550 just for example, this should be more then the modal that is in foreground*/
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Ujwal Ratra. I tried your suggestion but, unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, Paulo. Try hiding the modal before showing alert maybe this would help.

Comment: this behavior is not the best one for my case because the user shall be inserting more values in the modal dialog if the alert is showed. Thanks.

Comment: A sort of. But, as said before, there's a slight difference. In this sample user clicks a button (that has this propertie: data-toggle="modal") with the specific purpose to open another modal. That's not my case. When the user clicks the Ok in my code the modal will be showed or not. Thanks

Comment: When the user clicks Ok, you can check the conditions and then if you want to open the modal, then you can open it using $('#modalId').modal('show')